# i want to create Youtube Video Gallery using php but i get only 26 videos,is it possible to get more than 26 videos

Tags: php

```
<?php
   $xml = simplexml_load_file('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/UCayXdktyKEoJr7kQcEYXZhA/uploads');$server_time = $xml->updated;$return = array();foreach ($xml->entry as $video) {$vid = array();$vid['id'] = substr($video->id,42);$vid['title'] = $video->title;$vid['date'] = $video->published; $media = $video->children('http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/');
      $yt = $media->children('http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007');$attrs = $yt->duration->attributes(); $vid['length'] = $attrs['seconds']; $attrs = $media->group->thumbnail[0]->attributes();$vid['thumb'] = $attrs['url'];
      $yt = $video->children('http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007'); $attrs = $yt->statistics->attributes(); array_push($return, $vid); } ?>
<div class="youtube-video-gallery"><?php $j=1;  foreach($return as $video) {    ?><div class="youtube-video"><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=<?=$video['id']?>" target="_blank"><img src="<?= $video['thumb']?>" width="270"/></a><h2> <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=<?=$video['id']?>" target="_blank"> <?= $video['title'] ?></a></h2> <p>Published on: <?=$video['date']?></p> </div> <?php $j++; }echo 'video count : '.$j;?><div class="clearfix"></div></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use max-results in your query i.e

```
simplexml_load_file('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/UCayXdktyKEoJr7kQcEYXZhA/uploads?max-results=40');
```

The maximum value for max-results is 50. You can read more about it on [Youtube API doc](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_api_query_parameters#max-resultssp)

Answer (score 0):

You need to properly assign your url for getting the result from youtube api

An example would be `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?q=football&part=id&key=YOUR_DEVELOPER_KEY&max-results=50` //fetches 50 videos

Comment: maxi-results only accepts values up to 50

Comment: sorry i reedited ..:)Thanx for the mention

Comment: kk could you please explain briefly( here what is 'part=id' and where am i put my channel id)

Comment: part id is the channel id and developer key is the key provided by the yoyutbe for you..check here https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started..